# How to create a custom std::ostream which has an override for each primitive type

Tags: c++, std, stdout, ostream

I am creating a custom logger that I want to use as a drop-in replacement for a std::ostream.  I want to have overrides for each primitive type -- I do not want to implement a char-based streambuf thing (as you can see, I write to std::cerr anyway for now).

I'm getting a segfault with the following...  I am not sure why.  I've tried running in the debugger but even when I single-step through things, it's not clearly showing me why the segfault is occurring.

```
#include <iostream>

// A custom basic_ostream that has an implementation for each primitive type
struct Log : std::basic_ostream<char>
{
    Log& operator<<(int o) noexcept { std::cerr << "INT\n"; return *this; }
};

// I want my objects to keep using std::ostream
struct A
{
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, A const& o) noexcept
    {
        return os << o.x;
    }

private:
    int x;
};

int main()
{
    Log log;
    A a;
    log << a;
}
```

Comment: The issue is that the [operator<<](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) is not `noexcept` and is not `virtual`. Therefore `return os << o.x;` does not call `Log::operator<<`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  I tried removing the 'noexcept' from above (and making operator<<(int o) virtual) and still have the same segfault.

Comment: You can not override what is not virtual, what is not designed to be possible to override. C++11 added keyword override for to ensure compiling error on such attempts.

Comment: So.... This is something that's not possible to do then?  I've been searching for ways to do this but everyone seems to override at the streambuf level, which deals with chars.  I want to override at the type-level (i.e., int, float, double).

Comment: In C++ everything is possible to do. But when you want to design a class that has very different requirements than other class (like std::basic_ostream) then do not use that other class as public base class of your class. Otherwise what will happen can confuse you and others pointlessly.

Comment: Idiomatically this code shouldn't even compile (but I can see how it could; read on). Depending on the implementation you're using, your code likely invokes a protected base class constructor, `std::basic_ostream<char>()`, which does *not* initialize diddly in the base. `std:basic_ios::init` is never called in that case. I don't know what your plan was for your streambuf offering to your `Log` class, but as-presented there simply is none. I tell you this because that's very likely the source for your fault condition (it's likely blowing up on destruction of `log`).

Comment: You are trying to write into an uninitialized ostream and expect some kind of output, with no undefined behavior?  Odd....

Comment: I think you should customize std::streambuf instead of std::ostream to achieve what you need.